# How to show password recovery form after user enters invalid credentials three times

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

hi evryone can you help me please.. i have a code on my windows form application  using *visual studio community 2015* I have a **textBox** the name is **username** the other one is **password** and the last is **login** if the user want to login and it will get a tree times error here the problem I want it  automatically show the forgot password and how to recover password if the user is tree times error when he or she login the form. before I'll go to my database form i have no idea can you help please and explain how.

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLSERVER_VISUALSTUDIO_COMMUNITY
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txt_Password.PasswordChar = '*';
        }

        private void txt_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_USername.Text == "" && txt_Password.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password and user_name");
                txt_USername.Clear();
                txt_Password.Clear();
            }
            else if (txt_USername.Text == "jondygonzales" && txt_Password.Text == "sharkwebcaster")
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("successfully log_in");
                Form1 f = new Form1();
                f.Show();
                Form2 main = new Form2();
                main.Show();
                this.Hide(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact error code are you getting?

Comment: @AidenGrossman thanks.. I have no error but my point is I want to show the forgot password if the user is error in tree times of login the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is keep a counter which you will increase by one when username and password are not valid.

You check this variable value and when it reaches 3, you show user the password recovery form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int loginAttemps = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txt_Password.PasswordChar = '*';
    }

    private void txt_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_USername.Text == "" && txt_Password.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password and user_name");
            txt_USername.Clear();
            txt_Password.Clear();
        }
        else if (txt_USername.Text == "jondygonzales" && txt_Password.Text == "sharkwebcaster")
        { 
            loginAttempts = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("successfully log_in");
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.Show();
            Form2 main = new Form2();
            main.Show();
            this.Hide(); 
        }
        else
        {
            loginAttempts += 1;

            if(loginAttemps == 3)
            {
                RecoveryForm recForm = new RecoveryForm(); // You need to use correct Form here.
                recForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. so only have to do is put a condition that will belong to the else if of the username and password

Comment: I corrected the code in answer to make it more logical. The last `else` block is the one which you need to add apart from introducing new variable `loginAttempts`

Comment: what the uses of   loginAttempts += 1;

Comment: loginAttemps the variable to track the number of failedLogin attempts.

Comment: if  it's reaches 3 time's to track it will re directly go to the recovery form.  Thank you for sharing knowledge.

Comment: @ Chetan Ranpariya its really work.thank you so much